# Why aren't my images changing when I change their source attribute -JQuery Mobile & Phone Gap

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, cordova

I'm writing a jquerymobile / phonegap application where I need small icons to change depending on what the user selects from a drop down, or depending on different values coming back from the database.

Here is a quick snippet of the code

```
        if(sqlData[0][6]==1){
            myAlert('urgent');
            $('#icon3s').attr("src", './icons/Urgent.png');
        }else{
            myAlert('not urgent');
            $('#icon3s').attr("src",'./icons/not_urgent.png');
        }
         $('img').each(function(){
             console.log($(this).attr('id')+" src = "+$(this).attr('src'));
        });
```

As you can see, after changing the image source I went ahead and printed out all the images just to make sure the source was being set correctly and it is....

The image itself doesn't change though, even though the attribute has been successfully updated...

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide the html markup you are trying this code with? This code works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Really old post, but I ran into the same issue (also using Phonegap + jQuery Mobile).  Upon a tap event firing, I was attempting to change an `<img>` `src` to a different image:

HTML:

```
<div class="profileNavGroup" id="myTeamsGroup">
    <img class="profileNavImage" src="images/tempProfilePic.jpg" />
    <h5 class="profileNavText">My Teams</h5>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#myTeamsGroup").live('tap', function() {
    $("#myTeamsGroup .profileNavImage").attr("src", "images/tempProfilePic.jpg");
}):
```

This wasn't working, and after fiddling with it for an hour so I realized it was the image file.  After changing it to a different image, the image updated correctly.

Moral of the story: Perhaps the image you're using just isn't showing up?  Try changing it to another image (or change your image's file type) and see if that helps.  My image showed fine when previewing in windows or any other application, but it would never show up in my android app.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the attr. of the image, possibly your element is not getting re-render. Try to replace the element, i think that should work.

Comment: so rather than have an <img src=...> in the page use an <div><img src='default image'> and then rewrite the div.html ? will give it a try but it's a lot of extra markup

Comment: doesn't work - the default image disappears - the new image is not visible - the division is still clickable so it's still there but nothing new is rendered to the screen...

Comment: this should work but i am not sure why it's not working for you. As a alternative solution you can have both images and hide one as per your condition.

Answer (score 0):

If the icon is in a jQuery Mobile type element like a listview, you might need a refresh - like `$('#listId').listview('refresh');`

Comment: Thanks for the insight, that would have been a curve ball about two weeks down the road when I get to one of the apps other screens... however at the moment, it's just a simple image inside a simple division ...

Comment: heh, that gives me a stupid idea, gonna try and hide and then re-show the image and see if that forces a refresh on the element